# Facebook desktop application submission

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Our windows desktop application (based on Java Swing) has a functionality to publish on the user's Facebook account (all properly implemented using RestFB library).

While this works perfectly in Facebook's sandbox / test mode, we would like to go to production and need thus to have our application approved by Facebook (as the application needs `publish_actions` permissions).

To apply, Facebook requires to indicate the platform and, for Windows, it also requires a "Windows Store ID" and a "Windows Phone Store ID" which we don't have as our application is not available on Windows store (and it is not meant to be).

What should we do to get our app approved? Are we missing something?
(I understand that this is not a pure coding question but it is probably relevant for many developers)

Thanks,
Thomas

Comment: So how are you actually handling login in that desktop application – by calling the login dialog in a “web view” or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across the same problem. In the past it was no problem to register an app on facebook, set the scope and get the permission by the user to upload images or videos.

But at the moment at seems they will only support Windows (Metro) Store-Apps.

[See Bug: 'Submission of Desktop-Apps won't work' on facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/350765051748773/)

The first response of the support seems to be final :(

Comment: It's really a pitty. That's the problem when a platform becomes too dominant: they can afford to frustrate part of their potential audience...